# Fade out text and fade in next canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

So I have a canvas in my game which will display some text but I would like it to be if you have ever played *Clicker Heros* when you click theres some damage text displayed but its faded in and out slowly and kinda moves upward while fading out I would like to produce the same effect here

So what I have is a function which is called when the user clicks the *Terminal* I need the text to produce a similiar behavior but I am very new to canvas and not sure how to do so here is my current code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("terminalCanvas");
var terminal = canvas.getContext("2d");

terminal.fillStyle = "#000000";
terminal.fillRect(0,0,150,200);

function WriteToCanvas(){
    if(Game.Player.HTMLSupport == 1){
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 122) + 1;
        var tag = htmltags[rand];
        terminal.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
        terminal.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,1)";
        terminal.textAlign = "center";
        terminal.fillText(tag, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
        ClearCanvas();
    }
}

function ClearCanvas(){
    terminal.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    terminal.fillStyle = "#000000";
    terminal.fillRect(0,0,150,200);
}
```

Comment: try this. its a css and all you need is adding classes. https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: I would prefer a javascript solution overall

Comment: $('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft'); for example?

Comment: your trying to animate the canvas with that code the TEXT needs to be animated

Comment: Use `context.globalAlpha` to constantly redraw your text from 0.00-1.00 alpha (==fade in) and from 1.00 to 0.00 alpha (==fade out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A particle system is what you need. Bellow at the top of the code is what you need to do a simple and memory efficient particle system. 
Uses a particle pool. Dead particles go to the pool when their time is up. When new particles are needed check if any dead ones are in the pool, if so resurrect them, else create a new one. This avoids incurring the dreaded GC lag that particle systems can make work extra hard.

It may pay that you don't use the fillText (as it is very slow)  to render the particle, but pre render and use drawImage. Up to you.

Sorry I dont have time for a deeper explanation

```js
/*=====================================================================================
ANSWER code start
=====================================================================================*/


const LIFETIME = 1 / 180; // 180 frames
const YDIST = -140; // number of pixels to move over the life 
const MOVE_CURVE_SHAPE = 1.5;
const FADE_CURVE_SHAPE = 1.5;
const FADE_CURVE_ADVANCE = 0.25; // Want the fade not to start early on the fade curve
var particles = []; // array to hold live particles
var particlePool = []; // to hold the dead



// this function is called once a frame
function display(){  // put code in here
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.font = "40px Comic Sans MS";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillText("Click mouse to add particles",canvas.width/2, 30);
    if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){
        var p;
        if(particlePool.length){ // check if the are any dead particles in the pool
            p = particlePool.shift(); // if so get the first on in out
        }else{ // nothing in the pool so create a new on
            p = {};
        }
        // set up the paticle    
        var text = (Math.floor(Math.random()* 10) *100) + "!"; // the text to display
        p = createParticle(mouse.x,mouse.y,text,p); // set up the particle
        particles.push(p); // push it onto the active array
        mouse.buttonRaw = 0; // clear mouse down;
    }
    
    updateParticles(); // update particles
    renderParticles(); // and draw them
    
}


// sets up a particle x,y startung pos, text the value to display, p and object to hold the data
function createParticle(x,y,text,p){
    p.life = 1;  // when this get down to zero it is dead
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    p.text = text;
    return p;
}


// ease functions
var easeBell = function (x, pow) {  // x 0-1 pos > 0 
    x = x * 2;
    if( x > 1){
        x = 1 - (x - 1);
        var xx = Math.pow(x,pow);
        return xx / (xx + Math.pow(1 - x, pow));
    }else{
        var xx = Math.pow(x,pow);
        return xx / (xx + Math.pow(1 - x, pow));
    }
}
var ease = function (x, pow) {  // x 0-1 pos > 0 
    var xx = Math.pow(x,pow);
    return xx / (xx + Math.pow(1 - x, pow));
}
function updateParticles(){  // update the life and  death of the particles
    for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i ++){
         var p = particles[i];
         p.life -= LIFETIME;
         if(p.life <= 0){ // time is up this particle is dead
                          // move it to the grave
             particlePool.push(p);
             particles.splice(i,1); // remove it from the array
             i -= 1; // adjust i so we dont skip any
         }
     } 
}

function renderParticles(){
    ctx.font = "20px Comic Sans MS"
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
    for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i ++){ // for each active particle
         var p = particles[i];
         var fadeCurveVal = 1- p.life;
         fadeCurveVal *= (1 - FADE_CURVE_ADVANCE); // scale it down
         fadeCurveVal += FADE_CURVE_ADVANCE; // move it forward
         
         ctx.globalAlpha = easeBell(fadeCurveVal,FADE_CURVE_SHAPE); // get the fade fx
         var y = p.y + ease((1-p.life)/2,MOVE_CURVE_SHAPE) * YDIST * 2;
         ctx.fillText(p.text,p.x,y);
    }
}

         
/*=====================================================================================
ANSWER code End
=====================================================================================*/















/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js begin **/
const CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID = "canv";
const U = undefined;
var w, h, cw, ch; // short cut vars 
var canvas, ctx, mouse;
var globalTime = 0; 
var createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals;
var L = typeof log === "function" ? log : function(d){ console.log(d); }
createCanvas = function () {
    var c,cs;
    cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; 
    c.id = CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID;    
    cs.position = "absolute";
    cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
    cs.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.appendChild(c); 
    return c;
}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); }
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); }
}
setGlobals = function(){ cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; }
mouse = (function(){
    function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    var mouse = {
        x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, buttonRaw : 0,
        over : false,  // mouse is over the element
        bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
        mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    };
    var m = mouse;
    function mouseMove(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        m.x = e.offsetX; m.y = e.offsetY;
        if (m.x === U) { m.x = e.clientX; m.y = e.clientY; }
        m.alt = e.altKey; m.shift = e.shiftKey; m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
        if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1]; }  
        else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2]; }
        else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false; }
        else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
        else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta; }
        else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail; }
        if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)); }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    m.addCallback = function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            if (m.callbacks === U) { m.callbacks = [callback]; }
            else { m.callbacks.push(callback); }
        } else { throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function"); }
    }
    m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
        if (m.element !== U) { m.removeMouse(); }        
        m.element = element === U ? document : element;
        m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === U ? false : blockContextMenu;
        m.mouseEvents.forEach( n => { m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
        if (m.blockContextMenu === true) { m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false); }
    }
    m.remove = function () {
        if (m.element !== U) {
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
            if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) { m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);}
            m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = U;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
})();
var done = function(){
    window.removeEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas)
    mouse.remove();
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);    
    canvas = ctx = mouse = U;
    L("All done!")
}

resizeCanvas(); // create and size canvas
mouse.start(canvas,true); // start mouse on canvas and block context menu
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); // add resize event


function update(timer){ // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display();  // call demo code
    // continue until mouse right down
    if (!(mouse.buttonRaw & 4)) { requestAnimationFrame(update); } else { done(); }
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```